# jQuery's does not recognise prepended selector

Tags: jquery

I have this DIV, that has just been prepended as new content to the page:

```
<div class="acceptEdit">
     <a href="#">
          <div id="226" class="acceptIcon"></div>
     </a>
</div>
```

To be able to select "acceptIcon" class, I've got:

```
$('.acceptEdit').on('click', '.acceptIcon', insertEditRow);
```

Even when this way of constructing expressions on jQuery should be able to locate new contents, such as this class, it does not execute `insertEditRow` function. After trying to search about this on the net, I don't find the reason of this error.

In adition to this question, I would be grateful if someone tells me how is this way of locating objects on jQuery called in English. In Spanish it is "Mediador", is it "Mediator" in English?

Comment: You are prepEnding `acceptEdit` or `acceptIcon` ?

Comment: Has the entire `acceptEdit` div been prepended? With this variation of `on()`, it will only work for all future selectors that match the one you're using for delegation (i.e. "acceptIcon"-classed elements), not the parent you're using to scope the event handling.

Comment: Hi, the entire code was prepended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the whole acceptEdit div prepended to the page? If so, you'd have to select its parent (which is on the page at the time the script runs):

```
$('.acceptEditParent').on('click', '.acceptIcon', insertEditRow);
```

Comment: This must be. I am abot to try cchange first selector to existing parent before the prepend action. I'll tick you if this works.

Comment: What doodack said... if the div you're adding the listener to hasn't been added to the dom yet, `.on` won't do anything (it's not quite the same as `.live` used to be). It needs to be on a parent container that is part of the dom when the page is loaded and `$(document).ready...` runs.

Comment: Thats what I understood. Thank you Ted.

Comment: Solved. As far as the page lets me, I'll tick you (6 min). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.acceptEdit .acceptIcon', insertEditRow);
```

It would be better to use a closer ancestor than `body` if possible

Comment: Thank you 3rror404, already solved. I used the inmediate existing DOM parent before prepended content is added. Very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$('.acceptEdit').parent().on('click', '.acceptIcon', insertEditRow);
```